# Difficulty in MVC 4 with Json using ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I'm trying to pass a variable to my JsonResult but she gets nul so here are my codes from my JsonResult and jQuery

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult MostraTela(Teste testea)
    {

        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
```

and :

```
   var testea = JSON.stringify(dado);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Home/MostraTela',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: {testea: testea },
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data.success);
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("error");
                        },

                    });
```

Agora eu fui tentar passar uma model e esta esta recebendo nulo novamente alguma ideia do que pode ser?
I step up data: {testea: testea}, the error and if I step data: testea, everything comes null in my JsonResult

My model:

```
public class Teste
{
    public int idteste { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string birthday { get; set; }
    public string salary { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving the `testea` variable the name to make sure the action method assigns it to the same named parameter, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "post",
    data: { testea: testea },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.success);
    },
   error: function () {
       alert("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: I accepted the answer, you have a new answer to this new problem?

Comment: @user2004932 Thanks, I can't understand the language of your edit. If you have a different question, ask a different question on here :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the signature of the target method is a string, try passing 123 as a string, ex.

```
var testea = JSON.stringify("123");
```

Comment: I think @mattytommo's is on the right track, but still assign testea to a string.

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to pass JSON, set the `content-type` to `application/json`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("MostraTela", "Home")',
    data: { Id: 1, Name: 'Im a complex object' },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.success);
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
});
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MostraTela(MyModel model, FormCollection collection)
{
    return Json(new { success = true });
}
```

Class:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How do I get the model in my controller? I tried this but getting null

Comment: this code works for me, see if your model and your json have the same property names